# .htaccess password protect directories with no index file

Tags: .htaccess

How can I password-protect directories that have no `index` file? I want only the index part to be password protected, not the files inside.

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/foo/            Password required
http://www.example.com/foo/bar.html    No password required
```

I can make those `forbidden` by

```
Options -Indexes
```

but I don't want them to be forbidden, instead I want them to require a password.

Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain your reasoning? I mean, why password protect /foo, but not /foo/bar.html? What are you trying to accomplish? You can protect on a per file basis, but you indicate there is no index.html.

Comment: In a lot of documents sharing tools in compagny (as Sharepoint), they protect the directory listing but allow a direct access, if your boss give you a specific file url.

Comment: You can do this by password protecting index.php, but allowing other files. index.php could then be a php script that basically generates a directory listing.

Comment: I second Terrence M's idea. It's a lot easier than using htaccess (mod_require+setenvif+require+allow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out how to do it! :D

***First*** Put in a PHP-generated directory for those without any index page:

```
DirectoryIndex default.php index.php index.html /php_directory.php
```

***Then*** just password-protect the `php_directory.php` file!

```
AuthUserFile /full/path/here/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Log in"
```

Thank you for all your comments! (which helped me to get to this)

Comment: it's a really clean way of doing it! I really like it. A couple of days ago, I tried with a php_directory also. My solution was more complicated and at final, didn't works well.